# Python Fabric deployment on local and remote

Tags: python, fabric

I use fabric to automate a number of tasks which i run either on local machine or remote server.

All the tasks work individually. But what I want to is to have a new task that does some work on local machine (build an image, and upload) and the some work on server (reload the server)

If I run the commands manually they work:

```
fab build_file
fab remote deploy_file
```

here is an output:

```
> fab remote deploy_file
[localhost] Executing task 'remote'
[docker.me] Executing task 'deploy_file'
[docker.me] run: echo 'reload image'
[docker.me] out: reload image
[docker.me] out:


Done.
Disconnecting from docker.me... done.
```

but if I try to combine the local and remote tasks this is what I get:

```
> fab do_all
[localhost] Executing task 'do_all'
[localhost] local: echo 'make image'
make image
[localhost] local: echo 'upload image'
upload image
[localhost] run: echo 'reload image'

Fatal error: Low level socket error connecting to host localhost on port 22: Connection refused (tried 1 time)

Underlying exception:
    Connection refused

Aborting.
```

is there a way to do both local and remote tasks in single Uber task?

My fabfile.py:

```
from fabric.api import *

env.run = local
env.hosts = ['localhost']

@task
def remote():
    env.run = run
    env.hosts = ["docker.me"]

@task
def build_file():
    env.run("echo 'make image'")
    env.run("echo 'upload image'")


@task
def deploy_file():
    env.run("echo 'reload image'")


@task
def do_all():
    build_file()
    remote()
    deploy_file()
```

Answer (score 3):

I might be missing the point, but why don't you simply do something like this

```
from fabric.api import *

env.hosts = ['docker.me']

@task
def all():
    local("echo 'make image'")
    local("echo 'upload image'")
    run("echo 'reload image'")
```

Edit:

I see. Your code is basically ok. There is only one little detail. With following code you should be ok:

```
from fabric.api import *

env.run = local
env.hosts = ["docker.me"] # change this!

@task
def remote():
    env.run = run

@task
def build_file():
    env.run("echo 'make image'")
    env.run("echo 'upload image'")

@task
def deploy_file():
    env.run("echo 'reload image'")

@task
def do_all():
    build_file()
    remote()
    deploy_file()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. The reason is I want to run the same thing on local or remove servers. the pattern on fab remote xxx is really convenient. I can run something locally or remotely by putting a remote before the task. what you suggest can only be run locally.

Comment: The point of using the function remote() is to dynamically set the hosts. What you have has hardcoded everything to remote host which is missing the point. :-)

Comment: @DavidDehghan, I have just found solution to your problem. The answer is probably in using fabric's `execute`. See for instance [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/execution.html#using-execute-with-dynamically-set-host-lists). Is this what you want?